# In app purchases SKScene swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my app I have the following code to handling the IAP:

```
var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func buyProduct() {

    print("buy" + p.productIdentifier)

    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    print("prudcutRequest")

    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {

        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.price)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)

        list.append(product)
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

    print("transaction restored")

    for transaction in queue.transactions {

        let t:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {

        case "stars100": GameScene.numberOfStars += 100

        default: print("IAP not setup")
        }
    }

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank you", message: "Your purchase is completed", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    print("add Payment")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {

        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .purchased, .restored: print("buy" + p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {

        case "stars100": GameScene.numberOfStars += 100

            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank you 1", message: "", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

        default: print("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        break;
        case .failed: print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        break;
        default: print("default")
        break;
        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans: SKPaymentTransaction) {print("finish trans")}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {print("remove trans")}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {

        print("IAP is enabled, loading")

        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "stars100")
        let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject> as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {print("please enable IAPs")}
```

And then I've put this button to purchase the product:

```
if getButton1.contains(location) {

            for product in list {

                let prodID = product.productIdentifier

                if (prodID == "stars100") {

                    p = product

                    buyProduct()

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that when I touch the button I see only these messages in console: 
IAP is enabled, loading
prudcutRequest

And in the app doesn't appear the alertView.

How can I solve this problem and complete my IAP?

Comment: After the "Product Request" print, do you see the list of products?

Comment: No, I don't print the list

Comment: So there are no products?!

Comment: SKView (UIView) to throw an IAP party?  SKView is not a view controller.

Comment: After product request I don't see nothing

Comment: is everything set up correctly on your developer account

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think that I have to set the contract for the paid applications.